# Need to replace part of img src with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML document, i need to replace the img src with the one i need, for example:

I have this inside a HTML document

```
<img src="img/lists/temp/1/12345.jpg">
```

I need to replace it for

```
<img src="img/lists/1/12345.jpg">
```

This is the code i use to call the HTML:

```
$link->query("INSERT INTO table(titulo,url,id_cate,id_quien,id_marca,filtros,descripcion,cantidad,precio,subasta,condicion,garantia,tipo_venta,envio,fstart,fend,plan,status,envio_precio) SELECT titulo,url,id_cate,id_quien,id_marca,filtros,descripcion,cantidad,precio,subasta,condicion,garantia,tipo_venta,envio,fstart,fend,plan,status,envio_precio FROM temp_table WHERE temp_table.id_publicacion = '$id'")){
                    $newId = $link->insert_id;
                    $description = str_replace("img/lists/temp/","img/lists/",$description);
                    $link->query("UPDATE table SET descripcion = '$description' WHERE id = '$newId'");
```

I've tried with:

```
$description = str_replace("img/lists/temp/","img/lists/",$description);
```

But it doesn't work and it breaks the content of the HTML

How can i achieve that? Also i can have more than one img in the HTML document.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Show the code before and after the point. How are you printing the html on the page and how are you re-adding $description to the html?

Comment: Actually, that `str_replace()` should work just fine.

Comment: It works: http://ideone.com/k59xQY

Comment: Are you sure `$description` contains the string?

Comment: First i save the HTML in MySQL inside a temp table, then i select everything from the temp table and insert into the final table, but i need to replace the "temp" folder for the images, so i select the $description from MySQL and then replace the src, after that i update the Table. I'm gonna update the question with the code

Comment: What is the result when you output this new description? Cause this should work perfectly.

Comment: Not a spelling mistake, my table fields are named in spanish, just called the variable in english to set a difference.

Comment: It cuts the HTML after the first img, and that dissorder all the page. It's driven me crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this...

```
$description = 'img/lists/temp/'
```

Before you do this...

```
$description = str_replace("img/lists/temp/","img/lists/",$description);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this one:

```
$str = '<img src="img/lists/temp/1/12345.jpg">';
$rep = 'img/lists/1/12345.jpg';
$description = preg_replace('#(<img.*src=")[^"]+(".*>)#', "$1{$rep}$2", $str);
```

Comment: Thanks! i'm gonna test it and report back